# Missing quotes in JSON object. How to add them in?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, jqgrid, quotes

I've got a slight problem when passing parsed JSON variabled through jqGrid.
I am querying a MS Access .mdb file. The problem is there is an ID field which is an autonumber integer field in MS Access and does not have quotes when queried. jqGrid doesn't like this and that's why it is not showing the ID value in the table.

```
 var SQL = "SELECT * FROM test";
 var resultSet = myDB.query(SQL);
// resultSet will yield [{"ID":1,"name":"albert","9999999999"},{"ID":2,"name":"peter","8888888888"}]
 var mydata = JSON.parse(resultSet)
```

notice above how resultSet does not have quotes on ID value but the rest do. This is resulting in a table without value in ID column. How do I add quotes to the ID value before it get's parsed via JSON?

Thank you.

[image]
The whole code..
[image]

Comment: Are you getting a JSON string back or JavaScript data structures?

Comment: yeah it's in JSON structure, but when it comes to numbers and integers it has no quotes. and jqGrid won't show unless the value has quotes.

Comment: I realize that this doesn't answer your question, but numbers in JSON _cannot be quoted_; if they are, they're strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid can work with integers exactly like with strings. So you don't need to change numbers to strings. The JSON which you posted in your previous question contains `id` instead of `ID`. JavaScript is case sensitive language. I suppose that you will see values in `id` column if you replace

```
{name:'ID',index:'ID', width:60, sortable:false},
```

to

```
{name:'id', width:60, sortable:false},
```

Additionally I recommend you to remove `index` property from `comModel`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (item in resultSet[0]){
    if (typeof(item) === "number"){
        item = " + item ";
    }
}
```

<strike>Untested and headcoded, maybe it works.</strike> That was total crap and could not have worked ... the line `item = " + item ";` should produce an error because this is no valid javascript.

```
resultSet[0].forEach(function(d){
    d.ID = '"' + d.ID + '"';
}
```

Comment: I have another approach to test. My intention is to iterate over all objects in the json result and add quotes to the ID value.

Comment: "Object doesn't support this property or method." :/

Comment: Does `resultSet` instead of `resultSet[0]` help?

Comment: Ok, as I just have recognized, `resultSet` does not contain JS objects so my approach was useless. Can't help you with that sry...